# Binomial and Variance (again)

Tags: statistics

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$

I guess the answer is extremely easy, but I think I've missed something...

When we have a set of $n$ independent identically distributed variables (with the binomial distribution), we can deduce the variance by : 
$\Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Var(X_i)$
Then $\Var(X_i)=pq \:\forall i$ (with standard notation), because of the identical distributed variables, hence :  $\Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = npq$. 
But by using first the argument of identically distributed variables, we have :
\begin{equation}\Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i\right) = \Var(nX_1)=n^2\Var(X_1)=\cdots\end{equation}
Where is the error ?

Comment: Maybe $Var\left(\sum X_i\right) \neq Var(nX_i)$ ?

Comment: I guess this is the flaw, but I don't understand why. I assumed that it is what identically distributed variables mean, because they follow same distribution, and it is equivalent to taking one n times.

Comment: You see, $Var(\sum X_i) = \sum Var(X_i)$ only when $X_i$ are independent. So, I think that might be the flaw in the first equation. I doubt about the equivalence, because the variables are random.

Comment: You think there is a flaw in the first equation ?

Comment: Yes, I think you can't substitute $\sum X_i$ with $nX_1$ in this case. That's because they have different distributions, moments, etc.

Comment: But assuming identical distributions doesn't imply these are the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sum X1+X2+...+Xn the values of the variables might be different, the first equation assumes that the values are equal. So the variances do not coincide.

Comment: In other words, nX1 only depends on X1, whereas the sum depends on all the X(i).

Comment: You're right ! I see what the trouble is. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The identity
$$
\operatorname{var}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=\operatorname{var}(X_1)+\cdots+\operatorname{var}(X_n)
$$
applies if the random variables are **independent** or even if they're only **uncorrelated**. But in the expression $\operatorname{var}(X_1+\cdots+X_1)$ (where they're all $X_1$, rather than $X_1,\ldots,X_n$), they're nowhere near uncorrelated.